# HTML table for MS Outlook margin issue

Tags: html, css, outlook

Am struggling with an HTML table that needs to be pasted as is in the body of a Microsoft Outlook email.

When I copy the html output and paste it into the email body, you will notice that the margin around table 1 and table 2 disappears. For some reason it still appears between table 3 and table 4. Have you any idea what is happening here and how I can fix it?

Jsfiddle if you want to copy the output:

http://jsfiddle.net/Guill84/k6eevtyL/

The code for the table is as follows:

```
<table cellpadding="10" cellspacing="0">
    <TD valign="top">
        <table cellpadding="3" cellspacing="0" style="border: 2px dotted #c0c0c0; width:250px;margin-bottom:10px">
            <TD>1st Table</TD>
            <TR>
                <TD>1st Table</TD>
            </TR>
        </table>
        <table cellpadding="3" cellspacing="0" style="border: 2px dotted #c0c0c0; width:250px">
            <TD>2nd Table</TD>
            <TR>
                <TD>2nd Table</TD>
            </TR>
        </table>
    </TD>
    <TD valign="top">
        <table cellpadding="3" cellspacing="0" style="border: 2px dotted #c0c0c0; width:250px;margin-bottom:10px">
            <TD>3rd Table</TD>
            <TR>
                <TD>3rd Table</TD>
            </TR>
        </table>
        <table cellpadding="3" cellspacing="0" style="border: 2px dotted #c0c0c0; width:250px">
            <TD>4th Table</TD>
            <TR>
                <TD>4th Table</TD>
            </TR>
        </table>
    </TD>
</table>
```

Comment: Has nobody got anything to say?? :-) Is this a bug? *BUMP*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The margin CSS attribute is not supported in outlook which is really annoying for many reasons. You have to do a workaround and use padding or cellpadding/cellspacing to sort out spacing.

Heres a guide of CSS attributes available in each mail client: https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/